# Strange behavior in C++ while loop and ifstream

Tags: c++, while-loop, fstream, ifstream

So I have an issue where my functions won't work properly when I read input from a file inside a loop ex:

```
ifstream in(inputFileName.c_str());  //input file is a string
    string word;
    while (in >> word){
        cout << word << endl;  //this behaves as it should n prints all words in file
        test.insert(word, 0);       //this function won't insert the words !
    }
```

however if I do

```
in >> word;
test.insert(word, 0);
in >> word;
test.insert(word, 0);
in >> word;
test.insert(word, 0);
```

....
it all works just fine !! this is really strange to me, any ideas what could cause this ?

Comment: What does your file contain?

Comment: What's the definition of `test`?

Comment: The file has 45k strings one on each line. test is a class type of Hash tables.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as if the problem is probably in your hash table class, of which `test` is an instance.

Lacking a really good reason to do otherwise, I'd at least consider using `std::unordered_set` instead:

```
std::ifstream in(inputFilename); // `.c_str()` no longer required in C++11

// read the words into the set
std::unordered_set test {std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
                         std::istream_iterator<std::string>()};

// display the unique words:
std::cout << "Unique words:\n";
std::copy(test.begin(), test.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```